# JVM Runtime.availableProcessors() returns 2 when it should be 4

Tags: amazon-eks, alpine-linux, openjdk-11, cpu-cores

I'm running `openjdk11` on alpine linux in a container in an AWS EKS cluster.

The application determines the size of a threadpool based on the number of CPUs as returned by `Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors()`

This call is returning 2 processors even though the container shows that 4 CPUs are available:

```
# cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep processor
processor   : 0
processor   : 1
processor   : 2
processor   : 3
```

Any idea why and how to solve the problem?

**Update**

Doing some more digging (prompted by some great questions from @gohm'c in the comments), I found a way to add some trace log prints to the JVM with `-Xlog:os+container=trace`

```
[0.001s][trace][os,container] CPU Shares is: 1536
[0.001s][trace][os,container] CPU Share count based on shares: 2
```

Now, I defined in `resources.requests.cpu: "1500m"`.

I don't know why the slight discrepancy but I changed the value of the CPU request, and indeed the `CPU Shares` in the log trace changes accordingly.

I understand how the `resources.limits.cpu` value could affect the CPUs that the JVM sees.  But why is the `resources.requests.cpu` value doing that!  This seems like a bug to me?  Any thoughts?

Comment: Can you post the JVM flags in used?

Comment: @gohm'c - no java flags.  just `java -classpath my.jar com.myorg.MainClass`

Comment: Did you set in your spec resources.limits.cpu to 2?

Comment: @gohm'c no, it has `resources.requests` but not `limits`. And anyway my understanding is that `limits` does not limit the number of CPUs actually exposed in the container. In any case, `/proc/cpuinfo` shows 4, the mystery is why the JVM only sees 2.

Comment: Try add `-XX:+PrintFlagsFinal` to see your jvm flags?

Comment: Also, you built your own image for `openjdk11 on alpine linux`, or can you tell which base image are you using?

Comment: I will try the flags.  The thing is, when I run this same configuration on a local k8s cluster (`docker-desktop`), the JVM does see 4 CPUs. It seems to me like the way the 4 CPUs are exposed when running in EKS somehow fools the JVM into thinking there are 2. I built my own image.  It's based on `FROM node:16-alpine` and java is installed with `RUN apk --no-cache add openjdk11-jre`